# Jboss Mbeans visible in jmx-console but not in JConsole

Tags: jvm, jmx, jconsole, jboss-4.0.x

JBoss(4.0.x) has many useful MBeans (`org.apache.commons.modeler.*`) that are visible in:
`/jmx-console`

But i cannot see these beans listed in JConsole (MBeans tab).

Are these beans not exposed to outside world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBoss 4.x has its own internal MBean server, separate from the default JVM one (JBoss AS 4.x pre-dates Java 5 and its MBean server, so needed its own).

I believe that in JBoss AS 5.x you can tell it to use the JVM's MBean server, but I don't think JBoss AS 4.x provides that option.

> Are these beans not exposed to outside world?

Yes they are - JBoss AS's internal MBean server is just as exposed as the JVM's one, it's just exposed differently. JConsole talks to the JVM's MBean server, you need different tools to talk to the JBoss AS one.

P.S. JBoss AS 4.0 is eye-poppingly old (2004? 2005?). You really should update it.

Comment: Thankyou skaffman for the insightful answer.      In JBoss 4x, there is a JMX-Console Web-Application. I can see org.apache.* package MBeans data there. I want to use ZABBIX(a monitoring tool) to get data from JBoss via JMX - but when i give the Bean Names (to Zabbix) etc as displayed in JMX-Console, Zabbix fails to get data. It probably is talking to wrong MBean Server(or i don't know how to give JMX Bean name correctly). And i do not see any option in ZABBIX (or JConsole) to switch the MBean Server to talk to.

Comment: @StackUnder - This was a while ago, and i do not exactly remember - however upgrading JBoss probably solved it. Unfortunately, I do not have access to this setup now - to look that up.

Comment: @Jasper i figured it out. You have to add the following: `-Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl` and `-Djboss.platform.mbeanserver`